# How to get website content if its part is dynamically loaded

Tags: php, dynamic, file-get-contents

1st of all I need to inform you that im trying to get ceontent from a website which is for adults only so if youre under 18 don't enter it (I need this for the purpose of using their affiliate program) website url is showup[dot]tv.

I need to capture the number of currently received coins displayed in 2 places on the page of each girl (online of course). You can check this link which will show you where the numbers are on the website:
[image]

Below is the code which I was able to make (I have used girl Natusia as an example girl but you have to change it to any curently online girl). It's working so I can pass the 1st "Confirmation of age" page by sending the cookie and than I can get the string which I need but... since the number of coins is **dynamically loaded** I cant get the number... instead Im getting this **"- / - żetonów (0%)"**  can someone help me to get the correct "parse?" code? (im just a begginer):

```
<?php

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: accept_rules=true\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$fullstring = file_get_contents('http://showup.tv/Natusia', false, $context);
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '<span class="progress-text">', '</span>');

echo $parsed;

?>
```

Comment: Well. Ask them if you can get their API and you could make yourself some jQuery or JavaScript code, which will, let say every 5 seconds make a GET request for JSON file with your data and change it in your HTML, so it will me live and dynamic. I used to download whole site (same technique), cache it and get one value, but when downloading was corrupted, then I got no value and had to remove cache and load site again. API is best practice. Ask them for that.

Comment: Well I did askd them but they either don't have API or don't want to share it

Comment: If you want to scrape content, the best approach would be something like phpQuery https://github.com/phpquery/phpquery (disclaimer: I have been a contributor to that project)

Comment: Also.. when you are parsing the code, the value is the one, which you get in return. But because of some script on their site, which increases and changes the value (and PHP can't run JavaScript via cURL as far as I know), so it won't work. Or maybe look up their code (view page source) and find the JavaScript, that changes the values and you can make with the same way your "API" calls? I guess

Comment: I dont think that I can find working JavaScript code, I even saved whole page and it's not refreshing needed data :/

Comment: It will never refresh needed data, because the document is downloaded as it is. There is no way for PHP to wait for some JavaScript to execute and pickup refreshed data.

Comment: Some time has passed since I posted this question, really PHP is not able to read these numbers? Is it impossible?

Comment: @Fotis I don't think [phpQuery](https://github.com/phpquery/phpquery) can handle and run javascript and execute XHR calls that pages like this one here call to fetch some data. MichaiłAndriejBogdanow you need a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to scrape data populated by AJAX calls; or you can even reverse engineer the javascript and see which calls the page does to fetch the data, but it will be much easier and future safe to use a headless browser.

Comment: @ChristosLytras It can't, you're right. Something like a headless browser is a more suitable solution :)

Comment: Can you help me with some code? I only know basics of PHP :/